# CSS3 not linking to HTML5?

Tags: html, css

Could anyone tell me why my stylesheet wont link to my html text? I feel like I've tried everything under the sun and am now just staring at it blankly. It's probably something insanely obvious.

```css
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Konrad Zuse </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<h2> Konrad Zuse </h2>
<p> Konrad Zuse was a German computer scientist who is responsible for creating the worlds first programmable computer. </p>
<p> He also designed the first high-level programming language, Plankakül. </p>
<p> Born on the 22<sup>nd</sup> of June 1910 in Berlin his family moved to Braunsberg, now know as Braniewo, Poland. His father worked as a postal clerk whilst Zuse attended Collegium Hosianum. Zuse passed his Abitur in 1928, meaning he could go on to study at university. Attending the Technische Hochschule Berlin, now Technical University of Berlin, Zuse studied engineering and architecture both of which he found tedious. He began a path down civil engineering and graduated in 1935. Once graduated Zuse began work at the Henschel aircraft factory in Berlin. He was made to calculate routine maths by hand and started to think up a machine that would do his calculations for him. </p>
```

Comment: You could try putting `./` in front of your `stylesheet.css` - so `href="./stylesheet.css"` this just means to check the current folder - this will only work if your stylesheet is in the same folder as your `index.html` - what does you folder structure look like??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asked [over and over and over again](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+linking+applying+html) and solutions should have been easy to find and, using dev tools, even easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips.

When you load page right click on page and go to `Inspect element`. Then go to `Network` tab, click on `CSS` checkbox and refresh page. It will display css that it tries to load. If name of file there is white then CSS is loaded. If it is not then it might be path problem. It would be cool if you could post image of `Network` tab from console

Also. You are missing `<body></body>` and closing `</html>` tag. Take care of that first

Answer (score 0):

In order for your css to be linked to your HTML file, you need to have the proper path. If you link your css file as `stylesheet.css` then you will need *both* your files in the **same** folder (as shown below)

[image]

If you want instead to use a css file that is not with your html file, you would need to start your path from your html file. For example, if you have your `index.html` in a parent folder and your `stylesheet.css` in a child folder, your path would be `href="/resources/stylesheet.css"` (as shown below)

[image]

Lastly, if your `stylesheet.css` would be in the parent folder, then you would need to go up with `..` that means go back to parent folder. Your path would be `href="../stylesheet.css"` your html file still being the starting point.